# Visual Studio Code: Is it Possible to Open New Files in the *Opposite* Pane (When Using Split Panes)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, let's say that I have split the program into two editor panes, and I have file A open in the left, and file  B open in the right.  When I have the left pane (file A) focused, and I open a new file (file C), it opens it ... in the left pane (covering up file A).  This happens whether I open the file by `CTRL +` clicking, or by choosing it in `CTRL + e`.

Is there any setting I can change, or any other way that I can tell VS Code to open new files in whichever pane is *opposite* the one I have focused?

Comment: Use Alt+Ctrl+Click

Comment: @rioV8 `CTRL+ALT+click` works (for both `CTLR+e` and `CTRL+click` file selection).  Would you care to add it as an official answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click for the mouse in the editor window.

If you use **`Go to File...`** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), on the selected entry use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>